# ffmpeg encoding using ogg with opus container

Tags: audio, ogg, opus

I am wanting to send whatsapp voice notes and we are needing to convert sample.mp3 to sample.ogg (with opus codec) is this command correct?

ffmpeg -i sample.mp3 c:a libopus sample.ogg

Comment: Does it work as expected?

Comment: I came right wiht "ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -c:a libopus -b 19.1k -ac 1 -r 16k newfilename.ogg" on a windows box. When I did the same on a linux box I get the following error "Unknow encoder 'libopus'.

Comment: Seems that you're missing the codec. Try executing`sudo apt-get install libopus0`.